# Gmail API throws error while sending email, but still sends email

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I create an email with the following.

```
def createGmailEmailNoAttachments(self, messageBody, subject, toEmail, fromEmail, html=False):
    try:
        newMessage = MIMEMultipart()
        newMessage['to']=toEmail
        newMessage['from'] = fromEmail
        newMessage['subject'] = subject
        if html: 
            msg= MIMEText(messageBody, 'html')
        else: 
            msg= MIMEText(messageBody)
        newMessage.attach(msg)

        raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(newMessage.as_bytes())
        raw = raw.decode()
        body = {'raw': raw}
        return body
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encountered while attempting to create gmail email")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

I send an email with the following.

```
def gmailAPISendEmail(self, message, userID="me"):
    try:
        service = self.gmailAPIService
        self.GLogger.info("Attempting to send email message")
        request = service.users().messages().send(userId=userID, body=message)
        response = self.executeGmailAPI_withretry(request)
        if response is False: 
            return False

        responseID = str(response['id'])
        self.GLogger.info("Successfully sent email message with ID (" + responseID +")")
        return responseID
    except:
        self.GLogger.error("Failed to send email message")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

Where I execute the request in the function `executeGmailAPI_withretry(request)`

```
def executeGmailAPI_withretry(self, request, withHTTPObject = False):
    try: 
        response_valid = False
        num_retries = 0
        while num_retries < 30: 
            try: 
                if withHTTPObject is True: 
                    response = request.execute(http=self.http_toUse)
                else: 
                    response = request.execute()
                response_valid = True
                break
            except socket.timeout:
                num_retries = num_retries + 1 
                time.sleep(0.5*num_retries)
            except: 
                self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered in executeGmailAPI_withretry")
                try: 
                    self.GLogger.error(f"The Method ID : {request.methodId}")
                except: 
                    pass
                try: 
                    self.GLogger.error(f"The uri : {request.uri}")
                except: 
                    pass
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                self.GLogger.exception(tb)
                num_retries = num_retries + 1 
                time.sleep(0.5*num_retries)

        if response_valid is False: 
            self.GLogger.error(f"Could not resolve issue in 15 requests [{request}]")
            return False
        else: 
            return response
    except: 
        self.GLogger.error("An error was encounrtered in executeGmailAPI_withretry")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.GLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```

The problem that I am encountering is as follows. Sometimes, when I want to send an email with these three functions, socket.timeout errors occur during execution of `service.users().messages().send(userId=userID, body=message)`. My retry function will try to send it up to 30 times with some time delays in between. However, sometimes, when a socket.timeout error occurs, the email is **still sent**. This can result in several of the same emails being sent. From the code's perspective, only one email was sent, since `service.users().messages().send(userId=userID, body=message)` ran only once successfully without throwing an error.

So, for example, I had 4 identical emails being received, meaning that at least 3 send attempts had a socket.timeout errors in which Gmail actually did send the email and the 4th (or more) attempt executed without throwing the socket.timeout error.

Why does the Gmail API throw a socket.timeout error while sending an email, but still continue to send the email?

This creates a dilemma in the current situation.

1. If I handle the errors, then it ensures that emails that truly cannot be sent on the first try will be sent. However, it can result in multiple identical emails being sent, due to the false errors.
2. If I don't handle the error, then for certain, only one email at most will be sent. However, if the email truly cannot be sent, then it will certainly not be sent.

The ideal solution is that the Gmail API should only throw an error if the email truly cannot be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting longer timeout for it to be in `timeout mode`. See `socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)`.

This will force the script to wait until the specified timeout before raising a timeout exception. This way, you might be able to prevent premature timeout exceptions.

If it still doesn't work, maybe you could file it as a bug on [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

#### Reference:

- [socket.timeout with will cause api client to become unuseable](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/563)
- [Socket Timeouts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#notes-on-socket-timeouts)

Comment: Thank you. I have set it to as much as 10 minutes. Changing the timeout value does seem to change the frequency and nature of socket.timeout errors. 

However, in my experience, socket.timeout errors will definitely occur at some point in time, regardless of the timeout value. The socket.timeout error does not always occur in the program or when sending a message. But when it does, it seems to throw the error but sends the email anyways. Because I handle the error, this translates into multiple emails being sent.

Comment: if it still doesn't work, I think you might want to post this on [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker). There may be something causing the bug that google knows.

Comment: I have now submitted a bug to Google

Comment: hi @geekygeek, if somehow our answer has helped you, feel free to upvote/accept the answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)